# Chalk pckg issues

Tags: reactjs, chalk

```
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:4
const chalk = require('chalk')
              ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js from C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js not supported.
index.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\chalk\package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).

    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:4:15)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:43:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:2:25) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

facing this error

Tried to fix this. I also tried re-installing but still the same error